# BSoD (ntoskrnl.exe)

Tags: windows-7, bsod

So, I was playing CSGO and all of a sudden I got a BSOD. This is my first time getting one so I really freaked out. The system just restarted and started working normally. I just got a message

> Windows has recovered from an unexpected shutdown.

After doing a bit of research I found out that a driver named ntoskrnl.exe caused the BSoD to appear. As stated earlier, I never had any problems with this. It was completely random.

Here's some more info.

```
The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.  The bugcheck was: 0x00000050 (0xfffffa800251443b, 0x0000000000000000, 0xfffff8000307515f, 0x0000000000000002). A dump was saved in: C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP. Report Id: 120915-23680-01.

param1 0x00000050 (0xfffffa800251443b, 0x0000000000000000, 0xfffff8000307515f, 0x0000000000000002) 
  param2 C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP 
  param3 120915-23680-01
```

What should I do?

Comment: Use `windbg` to analysis the memory dump to determine the reason the BSOD is happening.

Comment: Loading User Symbols
Loading unloaded module list
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck 50, {fffffa800251443b, 0, fffff8000307515f, 2}


Could not read faulting driver name
Probably caused by : memory_corruption ( nt!MiAgeWorkingSet+425 )

Followup:     MachineOwner

Comment: memory_corruption sound like RAM issue. test your RAM with memtes86+

Comment: By the way... yes, "memory corruption" can by caused by faulty RAM, but it is just as likely to be caused by a buggy device driver. ntoskrnl shows up on the stack not because it's the culprit, but because it's the victim. Automatic tools are not that good at detecting the actual causes of crashes.

Comment: Here's a google drive download link. :D https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B03IaQLlRihMaGN0SHlTRG16S1E

Comment: check the permissions of the link. We can't access it

Comment: Can you try it now? I set it to "Anyone with a link"

Comment: @magicandre1981 OP has updated the link, fyi

Comment: What you uploaded was the minidump. The error log output shows that you got at least a kernel dump (memory.dmp) - that would be far more useful (but, it's possible it may contain personally identifying info).

Comment: Well how do I get that?

Comment: From the output you posted above - "A dump was saved in: C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP"

Comment: Oh, okay.. I'll post it in a few moments.

Comment: Before I post this on here I need to know what kind of info does this give away exactly?

Comment: Everything that was paged into RAM for kernel address space at the time of the crash.

Comment: I just finished playing video games for the last 3 hours. No blue screen, no lag. Do you think this is gonna occur any more? And another thing -I'm going to reset my whole system in a few days and just clean my hardware from dust and stuff like that. Is that gonna stop my system from having blue screens connected to this one?

Comment: update the BIOS to the version from 2014 (you use an older one from 2013). Also post pictures of CPU-Z (SPD and memory tabs). I have no idea how good your SILICON POWER SP004GBLTU160V01 DDR3 RAM is and maybe the RAM settings are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This isn't really an answer, but it won't fit in a comment.)

As far as I can tell, I don't think the memory.dmp file will be helpful. From the minidump, the problem happened in a routine called MiAgeWorkingSet. It had a zero in a register that was supposed to contain the virtual address of some structure in memory, and zero is never a good address. This routine has to do with the "working set list", which keeps track of which pages of RAM are being used by a process, and "aging" the entries.

The thing is, there can't possibly be anything wrong with that routine; it's a standard part of every Windows system and is called far too often; if something was wrong with it Windows systems would be crashing all over the place. The routine was probably operating on the working set list of a process, and that list was probably corrupt. That is, some of the data in the list was invalid.

The trouble is there is not a good way to find out how that happened. Literally any kernel mode driver in the system could have done it. Or, it might have been due to hardware problems, like an actual problem with RAM. A very slightly flaky power supply can cause intermittent memory problems too.

There is no clear indication here of what to do next. You could do the usual hardware stuff: Reseat your RAM, etc. Cleaning dust out of the heat sinks is a good idea (yes, overheating can cause this sort of problem too). On the software side, make sure Windows and all of your drivers, especially video drivers, are up to date.

Oh, and: If you're overclocking anything, STOP.

Sorry I can't be of more help. Maybe magicandre can do better.

Comment: no, he runs the CPU at 3.4GHz, which is fine for his  **AMD Athlon(tm) X4 750 Quad Core Processor   Max Speed: 3400MHz,  Current Speed 3400MHz: http://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=AMD+Athlon+X4+750K+Quad+Core. I never heard abut his used RAM: SILICON POWER SP004GBLTU160V01 DDR3 so I think here is the issue. wrong RAM timings, board not tested with this RAM.

Comment: Sir, this is the best explanation I've gotten. Thank you.
I think the BSoD was most likely caused by the corrupted processes (CSGO is the main suspect since it first closed itself for no reason, I got back in and after 2 minutes I got the BSoD). I will reset my entire system in a few days (cause my PC is full of unneeded stuff anyway), I'll check my RAM and clean my hardware from dust, just in case. I don't overclock stuff since I don't really do anything that requires a lot of power, I play smaller games like CSGO, Borderlands 2 etc.